# Will Coulomb law work if both the charges are moving with same speed and same direction?

Tags: electrostatics, relative-motion, coulombs-law

I read it on wikipidia that Coulomb law will work if both the charges are at rest relatively.
Will there be an effect of magnetic field also?

Comment: In a reference frame where the two charges are moving each charge will produce a magnetic field, and instead of Coulomb you should use the (more general) lorentz force https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force the total force felt will remain the same though

Answer (score 1):

if both charges are moving with same speed and have the same charge then their magnetic fields will be same and hence they will cancel each other out